# Can't resize Folder properties window

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've opened the properties window of a folder to view it's security groups, but the security group names are too long to be fully readable in the security tab.

There is no way to resize the window.

Is there a logical purpose for this, or is it just designed to be a complete pain in the ass.

Happens on Win Server 2003, and Windows 7.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/229507/cant-resize-folder-properties-window).

Comment: Just _how long_ are your security group names?