# How can I resize a window from the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I've done some research but I always get to a tutorial to resize the command prompt window, and I want to resize any other window from the command line.

Comment: Some links. http://superuser.com/questions/201714/auto-program-resizer & http://superuser.com/questions/240285/cant-resize-folder-properties-window & http://superuser.com/questions/79757/control-startup-window-size-of-a-program & http://superuser.com/questions/79757/control-startup-window-size-of-a-program  to get you started, many of them AHK which can be initiated from the command prompt , and not actual programming, just scripting with AHK. To add more info to your question, Tell of one quick exact example of a program, and the size and location you want it to land?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way may be to install [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com), set up an [AHK script](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) for [resizing the Window](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlMove.htm) and then launch the script from the command-line.